# In a MS SSAS Project, creating a Data Source View over Npgsql (PostgreSQL) Data Source produces 42601: syntax error at or near '['

Tags: visual-studio-2017, ssas, sql-server-data-tools, npgsql, datasourceview

I'm trying to create Data Source View in a Multidimensional SSAS project using MS Visual Studio 2017 with SSDT installed.
In the Data Source View Wizard, I select my Npgsql (v. 11.00) based datasource connecting my PostgreSQL 10.5 I created before. No matter which options I select or which tables I choose to work with in the dialogues that follows, after I click the final Finish button I always retrieve a message box stating that "42601: syntax error at or near '['" and preventing me from finishing the Data Source View.
I assume the Visual Studio keeps treating the PostgreSQL the way it would treat MS SQL using [table].[column] notation instead of the "table"."column" one PostgreSQL would prefer. If so, is there a way how to correct this behaviour?