# In a MS SSAS Project creating a Data Source View over npgsql (Postgresql) visual studio 2019 gives error 42610: syntax error at or near '['

Tags: postgresql, visual-studio-2019, npgsql

there is an answered question concerning this topic more than a year ago ( [In a MS SSAS Project, creating a Data Source View over Npgsql (PostgreSQL) Data Source produces 42601: syntax error at or near '['](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53650668/in-a-ms-ssas-project-creating-a-data-source-view-over-npgsql-postgresql-data) )
I'm facing the same issue today running visual studio 2019 community on windows 10. When I create the Data Origin connection everything seems fine. However, when I try to create the Data Source View, I can choose the tables from the database but no matter what I say about the relationship between them I always get the error:" 42601 syntax error at or near '[' ".
My problem is the way I use this tool, I do not write any code that can be modified. It's done by the system itself. The Data Source View is created by the wizard and as far as I know, there is no way to do it manually. Any idea about how can I overcome this error?